# jQuery alert if table rows change (Fiddle inside)

Tags: jquery

So what I'm trying to do, is execute an alert each time the top row of a table changes. Problem is, I regenerate the HTML every 10 seconds of so - so I can't figure out how to "listen" for changes.

http://jsfiddle.net/kYZYU/1/

```
<table id="theTable">
<th>Id</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Score</th>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>James</td>
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Peter</td>
        <td>25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Sally</td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
</table>


$("#theTable").on("change", function() {
    alert("This person took the lead");
});


//Goal: An alert every time someone new takes the lead. The problem is, at this point - the table HTML is regenerated every 10 seconds (it will be better solution soon), so it's kind of hard to "listen for changes".
```

What I'm thinking:
1. On page load, look at the first table row and save the value of the User Id , next time the HTML is regenerated, run a comparison?

Comment: `table` doesn't have a change event. What event changes the table HTML?

Comment: Fire a custom event every time you update the table, and bind that event to the table.

Comment: Good point - I'm not 100% sure how I can trigger the change actually. Perhaps storing the #1 userid and checking it when the HTML is reloaded?

Comment: This depends on what changes; the entire HTML file, or just the part with the table?

Comment: Just the part with the table. It's an AJAX call that checks a PHP script, then updates a div with the new HTML every 10 seconds

Comment: Inside the success function of the ajax request, fire the custom event e.g. `$('#tableid').trigger('update')` and have that attached to the table `$('#tableid').on('update', alertfunction)`.

Comment: Sorry for being annoying @kayen - can you elaborate a little? This is the ajax request - https://gist.github.com/jamespember/680e425ef4f94989cbd8

Comment: @user2656127 I've added an answer. Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will need to bind a custom event to the table first:

```
// table listening to an "update" custom event
$('#leaderboard-spot').on('update', function(){
    alert('Table updated, launching kill space goats sequence now.')
});
```

When your ajax request is successful and and your table is updated, fire the custom event on the table:

```
function loadLeaderboard() {
    var competitionId = $("body").attr("data-competitionId");
    var url = "leaderboard_api.php?competitionId=" + competitionId;
    $.get(url, function (data) {
        $("#leaderboard-spot").html(data);
        // manually triggering an update
        $("#leaderboard-spot").trigger('update');
    });
}
```

Comment: Fantastic - that is exactly what I was trying to do, but couldn't! Could I even specify just the first row of the table like '#leaderboard-spot table tr:first' or something like that ?

Comment: Yes you can actually, you just need to trigger the correct event for the specified element. You can even bind it to the body: `$('body').on('update', dosomething)` and then `$('body').trigger('update')`.

Comment: Ok cool, and I guess inside the update, I need to specify the userId - so it doesn't fire every time the HTML is re built, only when a new user hits the top?